# How to stream(segment) mp4 video on webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, video, stream

So i use free hosting, I have few videos on my server, everything works except videos need about 10-20 sec to load and THEN start playing so i want to use streaming. Problem is i dont know that field and hosting doesnt support node.js but php 7 i think.

Tried using video.js with hls but i have no idea how to use it, i didnt find any reasonable or good tutorial online.

so ANY help would be great, what to focus on, links to some examples, quite a newbie so detailed tutorial would help.

this is in html:

```
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.5.5/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="video">
    <video id="video" class="video-js" width="1024" height="576" type="video/mp4" src="videos/merci.mp4" autoplay controls data-setup=""></video>
</div>
<span id="naziv">test text</span>


<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.5.5/video.js"></script>
```

and i have this in my .js

```
document.getElementById('video_html5_api').src = "videos/roses.mp4";
```

there are other parts of course but video is selected randomly with random integer and then switch statement, and this all works. But dont think this is much of use for my question since i have no idea where to go or start. I know how it should work with segmenting video in small chunks but have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide a [Minimum, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and I'm sure we would be willing to help.

Comment: edited the post

Comment: that is because video.js changes structure and id of video element so using default id wont work

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anything special for this.  A normal video tag will do:

```
<video src="videos/roses.mp4"></video>
```

However, you're going to want to make sure the `moov` atom in your MP4 file is at the beginning.  To do this, you can use FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i roses.mp4 -movflags faststart -codec copy roses-optimized.mp4
```

I think you'll find that this will improve the situation greatly.

Comment: can you elaborate on that? like where should i add and use that?

Comment: @IvanJerkovic The `<video>` tag  goes on your page wherever you want it.  The FFmpeg command, you run on your computer to optimize the video before you upload it to your server.

Comment: @IvanJerkovic You cleared your cache and all that?  (And, you *do* have enough bandwidth to stream the video, right?)  Can you post a link to the MP4?

Comment: @IvanJerkovic That URL doesn't work for me.  Returns some HTML page.

Comment: hmm maybe cause i already accessed video? well this is html page that plays said video http://projectbestac.epizy.com/bestac.html

Comment: @IvanJerkovic Your video doesn't work for me... audio only.  And, that URL is totally different than what you mentioned before.  I don't know how to help you without seeing your video.  http://projectbestac.epizy.com/videos/voice.mp4

Answer (score 1):

Given what you said, this may be too technical for you. But if you want to stream quality video on a simple http server, you could try using MPEG-DASH. This would involve two steps:

1. Encoding your video into an MPEG-DASH format. This will provide you with several streams of varying quality. These streams will be adaptively downloaded by your users as the video plays... think YouTube.
2. Adding some extra code to your page to support this in the browser. I'd suggest checking out the [DASH IF Reference Client](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js).

I know this is probably not enough information to go on, but I can probably follow-up with answers if you are interested.

Comment: well your solution seems most promising, i dont need ANYTHING fancy, just to start playing video immidately (or 1-2 sec) and not wait 20sec. ive been looking and it requires mpd file if that is even file or use mp4box to segment mp4 file. iam just tired spent 5h already trying to figure this out

Comment: I've been using Sorenson Squeeze to encode video to MPEG-DASH, but it looks like the company that makes that went bankrupt last year. MPEG-DASH is kind of a pain to set up, but once you get it working you can provide great quality video that starts fast and won't buffer on slow connections.

Comment: To follow-up on my last comment, I'd like to find an alternative to Sorenson Squeeze now that it is no longer supported. This ffmpeg-only solution looks helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/DASH_Adaptive_Streaming_for_HTML_5_Video. I haven't tried it though. If you end up using it and it works please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

My first .mp4 video wouldn't play until it downloaded fully
I tried another one and it started playing immediatelly (streaming)
So it depends on .mp4 video would it stream or not

Comment: See my answer below for why this is.

Comment: @Brad not everyone can use **cli** and user need to download **ffmpeg** to to that

Comment: i think youre talking about caching. browser saves that data and plays much easier next time you load?

Comment: @IvanJerkovic your server needs to support **http range request** so that it can request the file data from whatever position browser wants. Learn more about it at [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests)

Comment: @Pogromist Anyone making a web page is/should be perfectly capable of downloading FFmpeg and copy/pasting a simple command into their terminal.  Far better than your suggestion... of what, giving up and not bothering with any video that doesn't work?

Comment: @Brad he doesn't make youtube so i gave working suggestion, my video that first was loading fully to play was streamed after supporting http range request.

Comment: well i guess other people viewing need to have ffmpeg also right? which is not what i want, iam looking for something that works on chrome, no extensions or some modifications on browser, i can make it by uploading video on my google drive and playing but for that i need to enable third party cookies in browser

Comment: @IvanJerkovic No, not at all.  Please actually try what I suggested rather than dismissing it.  All you need to do is use FFmpeg to fix your video, and it will play better.